# Existence of "multi" in US English

Tags: grammaticality, word-usage

I have kept the "Check Grammar" option in my browser **On**, so whenever I write anything wrong as per US English it gets underlined. This is also the case with "multi".

When I use this word in combination with other complete standalone words like *multibillion*, *multimillion* or *multithreaded*, the word "multi" gets underlined (in Red) which means it's not considered correct grammatically.

But it's not considered an error when used in words like *multitude*, *multilateral*, etc. Again *lateral* is a standalone word here but there seems to be no error.

Is "multi" a wrong word in US English?  (The said browser software was developed in the USA.)

This link [here](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/multi-) provides the details about the word "multi" but all of the words used above are considered correct here.

Comment: My browser does not mark *multibillion*.  Maybe yours would prefer *multi-billion* instead?  Just a guess.

Comment: *Multi-* is not a word; it’s a prefix. Usually American publishers do not want it hyphenated, although British ones often do.

Comment: Some browsers available on US computers use British spelling rules. (There's probably a switch you can set, but I haven't bothered to find it on mine.)

Comment: @GEdgar nope! it actually does not accept it whether hyphenated or not.

Comment: @PeterShor Actually sir, its not a question of setting options but the usage in US.

Comment: [The style sheet from O’Reilly](http://oreilly.com/oreilly/author/stylesheet.html#miscellaneous) says: ‘Unless part of a proper noun, close up words with the prefixes **“multi”**, “pseudo”, “non”, and “sub” (e.g., **“multiuser”**, “pseudoattribute”, “nonprogammer”, and “subprocess”).’  However, they make an historical exception for the familiar Unix term *pseudo-tty*, making an allowance for the accepted practice of writing that word, or perhaps recognizing that *tty* is an abbreviation that is meant to be spelled out as three letters, not pronounced like *tie*. It’s not a proper noun, though.

Comment: @tchrist Hi, yours' is a good explanation,but can we trust this style sheet from O'Reilly ,by trust I mean is it authentic? Will you please provide an answer with some more clarification. Thanks!

Comment: What do you mean: *is it authentic?* I assume you don't mean *does it comply with the standards set by the U.S. National Bureau of English?* But if that's not what you mean, what is your definition of *"authentic"*? Certainly, I'd trust a style sheet from O'Reilly more than I trust your current browser.

Comment: Yes, absolutely. I mean exactly the same i.e, to comply with the standards.

Comment: @PHIfounder: there are no standards. The closest thing is [Merriam-Webster](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/multimillion), which does not hyphenate them.

Comment: @PeterShor OH !! thank you very very much for that link. thanks a lot!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You were already given this answer by several of the comments, and it's already implied in polynym's answer, but let's make it explicit:

Yes, the prefix *multi* is valid in American English, and usually used unhyphenated. You can see dozens of examples on [Wiktionary](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/multi-#English) or [Merriam-Webster](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/multimillion). If your grammar and spelling checker fails to accept it, it should be overridden manually.

Answer (score 3):

For clarity, I often use a hyphen for some multi- words: *multi-threaded* rather than *multithreaded*.

That is accepted by the spelling checker in my current browser where without a hyphen it is underlined in red. There may well be a discussion about appropriate use of the hyphen; I tend to use one as seems right to me and not according to some arbitrary rule.

Comment: Actually, it underlines even in hyphenated form which means it is simply not acceptable. I need to know whether this prefix is valid in US English or not.

Comment: 'Using one as seems right to you' **is** using an arbitrary rule. (Though this one is certainly one I'd have in my arbitrary-rule-box too - where I can't find a dictionary to adjudicate, or where dictionaries offer a choice).

Answer (score 0):

I think context is relevant.

If '*multi*' is used in contrast to and alongside another word that is *not* a valid prefix, then, given the latitude that exists here, I'd opt for the hyphen.  So I might write *'I took the multivitamins'*, but in another context, *'In our experiment, we evaluate both single-threaded and multi-threaded software.'*