# Multi-parametric based scheme OR multi-parameter based scheme OR multiple-parametric scheme?

Tags: grammar, titles, best-most

I am a researcher and have developed a scheme which is based on multiple parameters to work. What should be the grammatically correct title for the scheme among the given.

1. A multi-parametric based scheme
2. A multi-parametric scheme
3. A multi-parameter based scheme

Thanks in anticipation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A quick perusal of Google Scholar reveals about every combination of wording, spacing, and hyphenation imaginable has been used both in titles and in text.

This is probably going to get closed as *primarily opinion based*, but I checked a few options on Google Scholar and *multiparameter-based* was the most common of those I checked that seemed to use one term consistently and be well written in general.

In a related question — [Existence of "multi" in US English](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/118021/existence-of-multi-in-us-english) — tchrist wrote "Multi- is not a word; it’s a prefix. Usually American publishers do not want it hyphenated, although British ones often do." and "The style sheet from O’Reilly says: ‘Unless part of a proper noun, close up words with the prefixes “multi”, “pseudo”, “non”, and “sub” (e.g., “multiuser”, “pseudoattribute”, “nonprogammer”, and “subprocess”).’ "

For a title, the easiest-to-justify options would be "Multiple Parameter Based", "Multi-Parameter-Based", and Multiparameter-Based". If you went with "Multi-Parameter-Based", be aware that some publishers will want the size of the two hyphens to be different. That is a matter of house style.

"Multiparametric" seems to be an irregular variant. *Parametric* means *of parameters*, so it can refer to one or more than one. Multiparametric suggests, if anything, multiple parameterizations of a system.